# Import file by file path entered by user

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-import

I am writing tester that run user scripts:

```
tester d:\scripts\test_scripts_list.txt
```

The test_scripts_list.txt looks like this:

```
test1
d:\123\test2
```

My program reads the command line with *argparse* module, reads each line of the `test_scripts_list.txt` and import each test file with `__import__` (that actually runs the test file).
This is working well.

My only problem is to import **d:\123\test2** that's gives me:

```
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

I think this can be solved by analyze the path name, add it to `PYTHONPATH` while running with `sys.path.append` and than import it. But it seems a complicated soultion.
Do you have a better idea?

Note: test1's path is already in `PYTHONPATH`

**EDIT**
My current solution:

```
# Go over each line in scripts_filename and import all tests
for line in open(scripts_file.scripts_filename):
    line = line.strip()

    if not line or  line[0] == '#':
        # Ignore empty line and line with comment
        continue
    elif line[1] == ':' and  line[2] == '\\':
        # Find the last position of '\\'
        file_name_pos =  line.rfind('\\')
        # Separate file path and filename (I.E [0:5] will take 4 first chars and [4:] will take all chars except the 4 chars)
        file_path_string =  line[0:file_name_pos+1]
        file_name_string =  line[file_name_pos+1:]
        # Append file_path_string to PYTHONPATH in order to import it later
        sys.path.append(file_path_string)

        import_name  =  file_name_string
    else:
        import_name =  line

    try:
        # Try to import test
        print  "Run test : %s" % line
        __import__(import_name)
    except ImportError:
        print "Failed! (Test not found). Continue to the next test"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [imp module](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html), in particular the `imp.load_module` and `imp.load_source` functions. Here's one way you can use them (from Mercurial's [source code](http://selenic.com/repo/hg/file/21eb048edc19/mercurial/extensions.py#l36), slightly simplified):

```
def loadpath(path):
    module_name = os.path.basename(path)[:-3]
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        # module/__init__.py style
        d, f = os.path.split(path.rstrip('/'))
        fd, fpath, desc = imp.find_module(f, [d])
        return imp.load_module(module_name, fd, fpath, desc)
    else:
        return imp.load_source(module_name, path)
```

Comment: It seems that I still need to analyze the line in the file , separate path and module name and then call your function.am i right?

Comment: Right now my soultion is :  file_name_pos = line.rfind('\\')   file_path_string = line[0:file_name_pos+1]   file_name_string = line[file_name_pos+1:]   sys.path.append(file_path_string)

Comment: The module name can be basically anything. I've updated the answer to show one way of computing it.

Comment: So now you just have to feed it a path name like `d:\test123\test.py` and it will do the rest.

Comment: Beside imp module that i wasnt aware of , you still need to compute the module name and still need to handle ImportError. its a lot's like my solution in respect of command numbers and complexity (i updated the question with my solution)

Comment: Except that you avoid *modifying* the global `sys.path` and so avoid weird import errors in the future! Having to catch ImportError should not come as a surprise?

Comment: Thanks. Avoiding modifying the global sys.path is indeed an advantage